# Is there any way to create sub headers (using colspan in main headers)with ngGrid in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I am new to AngularJS and now working with ng-grid.But I can't create mutiple headers as main header and sub headers.I am using AngulaJS version 1.2.12 , jQuery version 2.0.3 and ng-grid 2.0.7.I wanna create a grid with headers.Is there any option like colspan in AngularJS?Please help me.Thanking you in anticipation.

Comment: there is no such feature in `ng-grid`, but you could possibly alter the [row template](https://github.com/angular-ui/ng-grid/wiki/Templating) for your needs.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve the col spans, you can make use of the attribute ***categoryDisplayName*** to those columns in your columnDefs. If column is independent and don't belong to any category, dont specify this attribute.

If two or more columns are shown next to each other and having the same categoryDisplayName, the category spans across all such columns.

Hope this is useful.

Comment: categoryDisplayName only won't work you have to add a little more, see this plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/hRYMM03y0cOMFxcgG6dR