# How to merge ng-grid cells?

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

Is there any way to merge some of the rows and cols of ng-grid?
I want to add rowspan and colspan to ng-grid cells.Please, help to implement merging cells in ng-grid.

Comment: You should provide an example of what you want the grid to look like.  [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22630240/is-there-any-way-to-create-sub-headers-using-colspan-in-main-headerswith-nggri) shows a colspan in the header, if that's what you're looking for